# Не загружается grub

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, boot, uefi

Пробовал ставить разные дистрибутивы Linux. Проблема заключается в том, что ни один (почти) не хочет загружаться в Uefi режиме. А для его работы нужно именно в Uefi режиме его установить, иначе не работает. Был момент, ставил Antergos, он чудом запустился и установился, однако после перезагрузки подал тот же результат, что и все остальные. А именно, комп зависал так, как на фотке. Просто крик души, я уже не один десяток форумов накурил. (Заранее извиняюсь за некачественную фоту, поясняю: комп проходит инициализацию биоса, дальше чтобы загрузить флеху нужно попасть в Boot-Menu на F11. Попадаю в меню, выбираю UEFI режим загрузки с флешки, дальше он просто выдает черный экран с одной белой чертой, которая даже не мигает. И так постоянно. Secure Boot выключен.)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а о хелезе можно пару слов и дистрибутиве и как создаете загрузочную флешку. не понятно кто требует у вас UEFI